# A tricky proof of a Diophantine equation is valid?

Tags: logic, set-theory, diophantine-equations, incompleteness

Statement F. $\ a^n+b^n+c^n=d^n$ has no positive integer solutions $a,b,c,d$ for any $n=3,4,5,...$.

(Please don't comment on whether or not Statement F is true!)

$Suppose$ I proved in the Gödel-sense that Statement F is undecidable in ZFC.

a) Is the following theorem TRUE, and is its proof correct? If it is a valid proof, how can I formalize it in some axiom system? We certainly cannot use ZFC, because Statement F is undecidable (unprovable) in ZFC (our assumption).

Theorem. Statement F is true.

Proof. I plug in a=b=c=d=1, and I don't get equality. I plug in a=b=c=1, d=2, and I don't get equality. I keep going by using an enumeration of $\mathbb{N}^4$. But I don't finish the calculations, because I don't have infinity much time. Instead I ask: can I get ever equality (if I kept going forever)? No, because, if, say, $3^5+4^5+8^5=9^5$, then that would be a proof of Statement F $not$ being true in ZFC, a contradiction. So our Theorem must be true!

b) option 2: if we can formalize the above proof in ZFC, then that means we cannot prove that Statement F is undecidable in ZFC. But then, similarly, we cannot prove that any Diophantine equation is undecidable in ZFC. I have not heard of such result! Did you?

Comment: If a statement of this form is undecideable in $ZFC$, it must be true, but the undecideability usually cannot be proven within $ZFC$.

Comment: If we find an interpretation for which the statement is true and an interpretation for which the statement is false, we have proven that the statement is undecideable. Not sure whether this can be ruled out in the case of statements of that form.

Comment: What do you mean true? Is CH true?

Comment: True means it has no positive integer solutions (or they cannot be found, so large).

Answer (score 3):

Your argument is correct, and there is no difficulty formalizing it in any axiomatic system such as ZFC.  In fact, assuming ZFC is consistent, you cannot prove within ZFC that *any* statement is undecidable in ZFC, or indeed that there is any statement that ZFC cannot prove.  If you could prove that, then you could conclude that ZFC is consistent (since if it were inconsistent, it would prove everything, since anything follows from a contradiction!).  So you would have a proof that ZFC is consistent, within ZFC.  This is impossible (unless ZFC is inconsistent), by Gödel's second incompleteness theorem.

To be clear, this doesn't mean that there are no Diophantine equations (or other statements) which are undecidable in ZFC.  It just means that you can't *prove* such undecidability in ZFC itself (as opposed to some stronger theory such as ZFC+Con(ZFC)).

Comment: Let us call my proof that Statement F is undecidable in ZFC by PR. My above proof of Statement F is using heavily PR. So it is not a proof in ZFC. But what kind of proof is that? Is it a valid proof in the other system, where I proved PR? Also, it relies on an infinite hypothetical checking. Can it be written down with some kind of induction or what?

Comment: There is literally nothing unusual or hard about this at all.  You are _not_ using the proof that Statement F is undecidable; you are just using the _statement_ that Statement F is undecidable.  Call that statement P.  Then your argument is just a perfectly ordinary proof (in ZFC, say) of the implication $P\Rightarrow F$.

Comment: Your "infinite hypothetical checking" is just perfectly ordinary mathematical reasoning that can be formalized in ZFC the same way as any other ordinary proof that covers infinitely many cases (namely, you just have to give a formal mathematical description that covers the argument in an arbitrary case).

Comment: I am not confident using P implies F, if its proof is not a part of ZFC. P implies F can only be used in a correct proof, if it has been proven IN ZFC. This is how the whole building of Mathematics is built up, just open any Math book. (Otherwise why not using 0=1 implies anything.) Also, if "hypothetical checking" can be formulized, then suddenly I have a new short proof of the Fermat theorem. Good-bye Wiles, welcome me (and you)!